# PowerShell: Firefox version check using Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, firefox

Trying to uninstall firefox using a powershell bat script. But i need to know which Firefox version is currently running and what is the folder name under program files/! I go lots of long script like: https://p0w3rsh3ll.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/get-firefoxinfo/

but i just want something simple which just return the current firefox version.

Comment: Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product would be the command to check what is installed.

Comment: Do not use **Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product**. It triggers reconfiguration of every package installed on the system. [Ref](http://serverfault.com/questions/203449/wmi-query-of-win32-product-creates-events-in-the-w2k8-application-event-log)

Answer (score 3):

[Firefox specifically contains a command-line option to get the version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#-v_or_-version), as well as instructions on how to use it on Windows. This one-liner will get your current Firefox version (presuming you're in the right folder or your Firefox is in the system path):

```
$ffversion = [string](.\firefox.exe -v| Write-Output)
```

The `| Write-Output` bit is crucial, for now, due to a documented bug. The result is then converted to a string (also necessary) and saved as a variable here.

Comment: Can you please link to the corresponding Bugzilla bug, so we can vote for it to get fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Firefox is installed in typical location:

```
wmic datafile where name='c:\\program files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\Firefox.exe' get version
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try below command in PowerShell -

```
PS> gp HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |Select DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate, HelpLink, UninstallString |ogv
```

[image]

This will display a popup with all the version details of installed software. In there Add Criteria and Set the DisplayName to Firefox.

You will get the version.

On x64 machines, if you want to do it with gp, you need

```
PS> gp HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate, HelpLink, UninstallString |ogv
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$firefox = (Get-Item (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\firefox.exe').'(Default)').VersionInfo
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes